# TS React data import: "TS2322: Type '{ data: { key1: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'. "

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the data file I'm trying to import. it's inside the `/src` folder:

```
export default {
  key1 : 'val1'
}
```

In the top level component `App.tsx` I have:

```
import portFolioData from "../data/portFolio";

type Props = {
  portfolioData : { key1 : string }
}

export default (props: Props) => {

  return (
    <div className="App" id="appContainer">

//TS2322: Type '{ portFolioData: { key1: string; }; }' is not assignable 
//to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.   Property 'portFolioData' does 
//not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
      <Portfolio portFolioData={portFolioData} />
      // continues...
```

The Portfolio.tsx component

```
type Props = {
  portfolioData : { key1 : string }
}

export default (props: Props) => {

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

I think it is a type error; the Props object is not defining or passing the data file correctly. What's the right syntax for this? I'm also open to switching to .json data files if that would help in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you should use in your Portfolio.tsx is:

```
interface Props  {
  portFolioData : { key1 : string }
}
```

( The F should be uppercase ) just look at the declaration of the props in App.tsx

and you don't need it this part on the App.tsx:

```
type Props = {
  portfolioData : { key1 : string }
}
```

(you don't need it because you're importing it and it's not passed as a props.

Comment: Thanks. I tried converting it to an interface and also removed the type definition in `App.tsx`. But the error is the same

Comment: i just figured out that there is also a typo in the composant props you typed:
portfolioData instead of portFolioData